# Is it possible to get AWS Cognito user attributes in the Lambda triggers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sns

When some files upload on my s3, i want to send email to all of cognito user's email.
i made s3 upload trigger with my lambda. Here is the code.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
try:
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    text = response["Body"].read().decode()
    data = json.loads(text)
    print(data)
    transactions = data['transactions']
    for record in transactions:
        print(record['transType'])
    return 'Success!'

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    raise e
```

Then how can i do?

```
import boto3 
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp') 
response = client.list_users(UserPoolId='') 
print(response)
```

I tried this code it worked on my python id, but it didn't work my lambda.
Can you help me?

p.s)
when i execute that s3 trigger lambda code, i can find this message.

```
"errorMessage": "'Records'",
"errorType": "KeyError",
"stackTrace": [
 [
   "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
   2,
"lambda_handler",
"bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']"
]
```

]
}
But i can find log and dot on my monitor when i upload s3 file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get a list of your cognito users.

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp' , region_name='xx-xxx-x')

def print_users(in_UserPoolId):

    users = []
    list_users = client.list_users(UserPoolId= in_UserPoolId)
    users = list_users['Users']

    try:
        PaginationToken = list_users['PaginationToken']
    except:
        PaginationToken = ''
        
    while (PaginationToken != ''):
        list_users = client.list_users(UserPoolId= in_UserPoolId, PaginationToken=PaginationToken)
        for item in list_users['Users']:
            users.append( item )
        if 'PaginationToken' in list_users:
            PaginationToken = list_users['PaginationToken']
        else:
            PaginationToken = ''

    for user_rec in users:
        user = user_rec['Username']
        print(user)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    UserPoolId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'    
    print_users(UserPoolId)
```